# Polynomial inverse

Tags: algorithm, math, solver, inverse

I have a polynomial of the fifth order:

y = ax<sup>5</sup> + bx<sup>4</sup> + cx<sup>3</sup> + dx<sup>2</sup> + ex + f

The coefficients a-f are known and I need to calculate x for a given y. I could probably use the Newton-Raphson algorithm or similar, but would prefer a non-iterative solution if possible.

Edit: I guess I didn't think this through enough before posting my question. My polynomial coefficients have been calculated from sampled data and in this special case there is only one root. It didn't pass my mind that there, of course, might be five different roots in the general case. I think I will fit the sampled data to an inverse polynomial as well, and use that to calculate x from y.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-iterative"?

Comment: And what is your question? Also this would be better suited to http://mathoverflow.net/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a problem with exact solutions for every a-f and is an important math problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function  Do you have any restrictions on a-f? Otherwise, you won't probably won't be able to do much better than iterative.

Comment: An iterative solution might end up being faster and more accurate anyway. Newton-Raphson converges extremely fast, and many of the special quintics that have analytic solutions also have an extremely large number of calculations anyway, each capable of introducing their own roundoff errors.

Comment: Also if you need all the solutions, you could find one by N-R, divide `ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f - y` by `x-solution` and then solve the resulting quartic using the formula. Works in principle, but I don't know how numerically stable it is especially considering that `solution` is only approximate.

Comment: @Steve: stability is really a concern here. There are two methods by which you can deflate, and one should either deflate by the smallest root or by the largest (and pick the corresponding method). Actually Jenkins-Traub algorithm alleviates this problem quite elegantly.

Comment: @Anlo - Can't help but think that given you start from sampled data and know there is only one root that the polynomial may not be the place to start. Can you not just work directly with the data? I assume the data is at least a little noisy, or this would be trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finding roots of polynomials is difficult and tricky. Getting a stable robust algorithm will get you headache. Newton + root removal seems a great idea, but making this work correctly is really painful.

One obvious problem is the stability of the root removal. One other problem is complex roots. One more difficult problem is (numerically) multiple roots, where you lose a lot of precision.

The state-of-art black box algorithm is [Jenkins-Traub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_method). However, it is difficult to implement so you will have to find (or pay for) an implementation somewhere.

Nevertheless, if you have access to a linear alebra package, a simple, robust, stable, and efficient way is to compute the eigenvalues of the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). This is what eg. GSL does.

Comment: FYI there is an open source c++ implementation (BSD license) of the Jenkins-Traub algorithm called [RPOLY++](https://github.com/sweeneychris/RpolyPlusPlus)

Answer (score 2):

J Trana's sort of answered this already, but the answer is that you can't in general find an algorithm for this (this is the mathematical result that made Galois famous).

Also, if this is anything other than a homework problem, you probably don't want an algorithm to solve the thing in radicals anyway, since this will be numerically badly behaved.

Comment: It's distressing that Galois *invented* abstract algebra faster than most mathematicians can *study* it.

Comment: Your first sentence is unclear. There are closed form solutions for the quintic, but they involve hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Ok, if Anlo looks at this: You cannot write down a solution to a general cubic using radicals. To Alexandre: I'm pretty certain that given the question above, Anlo wasn't thinking about hypergeometric functions.

Comment: if hypergeometric functions were simple to compute, this would have given a straightforward answer. Unfortunately they are not.

Comment: Yes. Indeed you can say this via the language of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_functions: Hypergeometric functions can only be expressed as infinite series. Anyway, I think we're writing that we agree with each other so we can probably stop typing now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Newton-Raphson will only get you one solution. There could be up to 5 of them for a quintic.

If you want all the solutions
you either need to pair Newton-Raphson with root-removal or use something a little more robust.

One common method is using [Sturm polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: This is incorrect; N-R can give you all five roots.    You just have to shift your starting point and bounds.

Comment: @duffymo: except that basins of convergence are highly irregular, so you cannot really select what root you'll end finding. Using Sturm's theorem to locate the roots and then polish them with NR could be a good idea, but possible multiple roots (ie. two roots within sqrt(epsilon)) ae a big concern.

Comment: A single run of N-R will only get you one solution. Guessing where to start your next run so that you get a different one is "kinda hard". However the methods mentioned by Alexandre C are probably more efficient and robust anyway.